SQLAlchemy to_tsquery multiple
Suggest a SQLAlchemy request to implement a request like
select to_tsvector('russian', txt) @@ (to_tsquery('russian', 'большой & вес') || to_tsquery('russian', 'запрос'))
     , txt
from test1


https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#specifying-the-regconfig-with-match-or-custom-operators
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.to_tsvector
Probably something like this:
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func

q = select(
func.to_tsvector('russian', test1.c.txt).bool_op("@@")(func.to_tsquery('russian', '(большой & вес) | запрос')),
test1.c.txt)


I placed the OR inside the to_tsquery itself.  I'm not sure if that is what you intended.
